# data in $scope not loading in the view in angularjs for dynamically loaded html

Tags: html, angularjs, dynamic, view, scope

I am loading the HTML in a tab. After loading the HTML in a div. I am triggering the controller. when the controller is triggered I have the data in the controller. That data is not populating in the HTML view. Is there any suggestion on calling a controller or loading the data into HTML??

```
 $('<div id = '+ createChannelTabId +'Properties'+ ' ng-controller="channelHomeCtrl" ng-bind="msg"> </div>').appendTo("#" + createChannelTabId);

        $('body').injector().invoke(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
                $compile($("#" + createChannelTabId + "Properties"))($rootScope);
                $rootScope.$apply();
            });
       var modalFieldProperties = $("#" + createChannelTabId + "Properties");
            modalFieldProperties.html(loadHTML("channelHome.html"));
            $("#" + createChannelTabId + "Link")[0].click();

         angular.bootstrap($("#" + createChannelTabId), ['ChannelModule']);
```

when the controller is called I am doing this inside the controller

```
    MDChannelModule.controller('channelHomeCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
    debugger;
        MDBPMUtils.showWaitCursor();

                $scope.query = {};

                 $scope.queryBy = 'description';
        $scope.items =
            $http.get("/mondrestws/services/binData/getListOfBinDataHeaderWithAccessRights/",{params : {foreignKeyType:"channelJSon"} }).then(function(res){
                            debugger;
                            channelData = res.data;
                if(res.data.length > 0){
                                     document.getElementById("emptyDTImg").style.display = "none";

                            $scope.items = angular.fromJson(res.data); 

                                }else{
                                     $scope.items = {};
                                    document.getElementById("emptyDTImg").style.display = "inline";

                                }
                MDBPMUtils.showDefaultCursor();
            },
            function(data) {
                MDBPMUtils.showMessage(data.status,data);
            });
)}
```

even then the data is not loading in the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="channelHomeCtrl">
<div class="infobox infobox-green" id="{{i.binDataId}}" ng-click ="setSectedValue(i)" ng-style="{ 'width' : width}" style=" margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px; padding: 2px 3px 2px 9px; height: 55px; border: 1px solid; border-radius: 8px; " ng-repeat="i in items| filter:query" >
    <div class="infobox-icon">
        <img src="../images/system/decisionTree.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="infobox-data">
        <span class="infobox-data-number action-buttons">
            <a style="font-size: 18px;white-space: nowrap;width: 18em;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;" title="{{getChannelName(i)}}" href="#/channelList" ng-click="setLink(i)">{{getChannelName(i)}}</a>
        </span>
        <div class="infobox-content" style="font-size: 12px">
            <i class="fa fa-list-ol bigger-90 blue"></i> {{i.version}}
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-130 blue"></i> {{i.binDataUpdateUserName}}
            </span> &nbsp;on {{i.binDataUpdatedOn}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you log and check what is printed for angular.fromJson(res.data) and also the response res.data

Comment: I don't see items  used in your dynamic HTML.Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: yes @Crazy Mac the res.data is fine it is giving me the proper array

Comment: @Rohan kawade i will post the content of the dynamic html where the data needs to be loaded

Comment: @AMITHGUJJAR If the returned object is an array, are you iterating and displaying the objects inside the array ? Also if it is just an array, why do you use angular.fromJson() ?

Comment: @crazy Mac i am pretty much shore it is proper because when i am loading this html using $routeprovider it was proper. when i moved the html inside the tab. I was not able to call the controller. even after calling it not able to load the data in html

Comment: In the HTML where are you calling the JS function to fetch the array? I am not sure if the scope is lost or reset, have to see your function call

Comment: you can see now, i have added the function. when i load the html the cursor will come into that controller, i am able to get the data in the call.

Comment: Why do you want to call the controller rather just calling a function which can populate the required data for you. I am not sure if this is a good practice to do it. I dont think it is being called before the view is loaded. Can you make a fiddle for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `$scope.$apply()` in `then` function after data is loaded from the service.

```
$scope.items = angular.fromJson(res.data);
$scope.$apply();
```